# Wait for an event to fire using tasks in .net 4

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, task

I have function A that calls function B from an external class that I cannot modify. Function B fires an event when completed on which I subscribed the doSomeStuff function.  I only want to finish Function A when doSomeStuff is finished. I can only use .Net 4, so no use of async etc.. I currently have this setup which freezes my program;

```
static EventWaitHandle _WaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public void functionA()
{
  functionB.completed += doSomeStuff;
  Task runFunctionB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { functionB(); });
  _WaitHandle.WaitOne(); 
}

public void doSomeStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // do stuff
  WaitHandle.Set();
}
```

I would expect task runFunctionB to execute as a seperate thread and therefore ending at my doSomeStuff function, but it seems not to do anything...?

Comment: Are you sure that the `completed` event delegate is being fired and that`doSomeStuff` is actually being called?

Comment: Alex, my program freezes and when I restart I do not see any evidence that function B has run. It seems that when WaitOne is called everything stops.../?

Comment: Have you tried running `functionB` synchronously (not using a task or `ManualResetEvent`) and ensured that it calls the `doSomeStuff` event handler?

Comment: absolutely, that is what I am trying to replace with this setup now. It is a helper function so I want my program only to call FunctionA and be sure that all is completed when it returns. Are you saying this setup should be good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `WaitHandle` you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and wait for `TaskCompletionSource<T>.Task`.

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

public void functionA()
{
  functionB.completed += doSomeStuff;
  Task runFunctionB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { functionB(); });

  completionSource.Task.ContinueWith((result)=> 
  {
     //Do whatever
  });
}

public void doSomeStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
    completionSource.SetResult(null);
}
```

> I can only use .Net 4, so no use of async etc..

That is a misconception. You can use async-await in .Net 4.0 using [BCL.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) nuget package given that you have Visual studio 2012 or higher still targeting .Net 4.0.

In which case you can await the Task.

```
public async Task functionA()
{
  functionB.completed += doSomeStuff;
  Task runFunctionB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { functionB(); });

  await completionSource.Task;
  //Do whatever; event is raised
}
```

Comment: Hey Sriram, just checked it in the debugger and ContinueWith only waits with execution for whatever is in its brackets, it does allow functionA to continue, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Bastiaan What actually you wanted to do? Maybe second part of my answer can help you? I guess it does what you want. If not, please make your question clear as what you want, what you have and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ Sriram, that second part is exactly what I need, pause execution of A till B and doSomeStuff are finished. However is that not possible without the nuget package, uing the TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: @Bastiaan Yes it is possible to do without the nuget package but you need to block the calling thread. Which is what exactly you have in your question with `_WaitHandle.WaitOne()`. Awaiting doesn't blocks the calling thread. You can also move all the code after the `_WaitHandle.WaitOne(); ` to the `ContinueWith` which is effectively same as `await`.